# Stock not reduce after placed the order in Magento 2 after enabling MSI

Tags: magento2.3.1, manage-stock, msi

As I mentioned in the question, I enabled the MSI module in my Magento 2 store. Product Qty is not reducing from the stock until I complete the shipment.

Is there any way to reduce the product Qty once placed the order?

Comment: Hey @Mujahidh did you find any solution for this problem?

Comment: Any solutions here?

Answer (score 0):

**Problem: During the order placement and fulfilment processes, Magento's MSI implementation will not decrement stock on order placement - it will only do so on order shipment and refund.**

Try this extension, it can help to solve your issue:

https://github.com/AmpersandHQ/magento2-disable-stock-reservation

Answer (score 0):

In Magento when you enable MSI, it works differently than without MSI. With MSI there are two different stock figures one is available qty and another one is reserve qty. For example -:

Product A -

Available Qty = 100
Reserved Qty = 100

When customer buys Product A, the available qty goes down to 99 and reserve qty remains 100. Reserve qty only goes to 99 when order gets shipped.

In a nutshell, it is working as expected, the available qty is getting reduced for the website which means you can’t sold more than you have in the stock. Hope the above makes sense.